# A question of optimisation and memory

Tags: android, memory, android-activity, android-intent

I want to know when im starting an activity using an Intent is the main activity(main) still in memory when im in subactivity?

Comment: And another, file strings.xml variables defined there always stay in memory during life of application ?

Comment: Simply you can check it with memory profile tools....

Comment: where i can take this tools ?

Comment: These are two links, where yo can get better knowledge about those tools http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147172/what-android-tools-and-methods-work-best-to-find-memory-resource-leaks and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857114/how-to-do-memory-profiling-for-an-android-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read basics related to activity Lifecycle http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html If you want to clear(close) main-activity after starting new one(sub-activity) using intent, then you have to close it(main activity) manually. Android is going to take care of that all things related to activity lifecycle, why you want to close main-activity?

Comment: Im thinking of optimisation so thats why i need to think about that.