# Memory issues on Android Device: how to approach them?

Tags: android

Apps work proper in emulator but while getting into device it crashes because of memory issues..

Can anyone please tell me how to do memory testing?

Comment: This question was already answered in StackOverFlow. Search in the site as : "How to discover memory usage of my application in Android." This will give you your answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112671/android-memory-analysing-eclipse-memory-analyzer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use tools like DDMS, Eclipse MAT or YourKit ([www.yourkit.com](http://www.yourkit.com)) to analyze memory. Memory issues often relate to bitmaps not being recycled properly or just using too many/large images at the same time.
Note that bitmaps are in the **native** heap!

You need to create a hprof file (look for the Debug class of the Android SDK) and then load it into one of the above mentioned profiler tools.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html#dumpHprofData(java.lang.String)

See these links:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html

https://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/hprof-conv.html