# Is there any open source profilers exists for android

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, profiler

I am a working on android application development. I am using eclipse IDE. I want to have any profilers if present for android. when I was java server side programmer I used to use JProfiler in netbeans.

I want to get detail information both in graphical and in chat format about memory allocation, thread creation etc while my application is running. Is there any such tool exists for android?

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you can find open source, but look here

[Profiling with Traceview and dmtracedump](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html)

Also this thread might help
[How to do memory profiling for an android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112671/android-memory-analysing-eclipse-memory-analyzer)

Answer (score 2):

I'd highly recommend checking out DDMS:
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html