# Memory Analyzer Tool in android?

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I just want to know how to work with Memory analyzer tool in android. Please tell me how to do this to know about memory leaks for a particular project. Can someone give me step wise procedure for this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1. Open DDMS perspective in Eclipse.
2. Select *Devices* tab.
3. Choose a process you want to make a dump for.
4. Click *Dump HPROF file* button. The dump will be made and MAT window will be opened, assuming MAT is installed.
5. Choose *Leak Suspects Report* in the wizard window and click *Finish*.

That's all. You'll se a list of possible leaks, but some of them are false-positive. I recommend you to run an activity you want to check leaks in several times and then run MAT again.

Comment: Thank You,let me check it out......Actually i want to know memory leak for a particular project or activity how would i load a particular project for memory leak

Comment: 3.Choose a process you want to make a dump for...what is the process here...i didnt get

Comment: I hope you don't have thousands of leaks so it will not be so difficult to find all leaks for a particular object. But I don't think MAT has such a feature to search leaks of some objects. It just searches all possible leaks.

Comment: When you open the Devices tab in the DDMS perspective, you'll see a list of devices and for every device there will be a list of processes that are launched on this device. One of this processes will be your application's process. It has a name equal to a package name of your application. Select this process and follow the next step.

Comment: Hey thanks for ur reply...when i clicked the Dump hprof file i am getting the following error::: hprof: can't open /sdcard/profileit.ImageDemo.hprof-hptemp: Permission denied.

Comment: Sounds strange. I've never faced such an error. Try googling it.

Comment: Try using another device or emulator.

Comment: Ya i tried with different emulators but still getting the same error...Is there any other way to find the memory leaks without using MAT...Any other tool for memory analyzing...

Comment: Maybe, but MAT is the most popular I think and I've worked only with it.

Answer (score 4):

Try [Using the Memory Analyzer Tool (MAT)](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/)

Look at these articles:

- [Using DDMS](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html)
- [Track Memory Allocations](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/track-memory-allocations.html)
- [Avoiding memory leaks](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)

Also look at these SO Posts:

- [Android ==> Memory Analysing ==> Eclipse memory analyzer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112671/android-memory-analysing-eclipse-memory-analyzer)
- [What Android tools and methods work best to find memory/resource leaks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147172/what-android-tools-and-methods-work-best-to-find-memory-resource-leaks)

Comment: Thank You,let me check it out

Comment: Actually i want to know memory leak for a particular project or activity how would i load a particular project for memory leak

Comment: while using DDMS mode i am getting the following error:::       hprof: can't open /sdcard/profileit.ImageDemo.hprof-hptemp: Permission denied.

Answer (score 1):

Write to hprof fails when you have not used android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. As a special case when you are testing on device, check if your SD card is connected in Charge ONLY mode otherwise you wont have write access on SD Card

Answer (score 0):

- Install [MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/downloads.php).
- Go to Tools->Android ->Android device monitor(DDMS)
- In the top left side under **Devices**,select the project name and
  click **Update Heap**.
- Then Click **Dump HPROF** File and saved it in desktop.
- Then run the Command prompt and point out the Android-sdk directory.

  *For an Example:* hprof-conv is located in E directory. So run the
  command as `cd android/sdk/platform-tools`.
- Then finally run this command by referring this [doc](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/hprof-conv.html) to convert this file format to read it in MAT.

  *E:\Android\sdk\platform-tools>* `hprof-conv "C:\Users\Steve\Desktop\yourfilename.hprof"
  "C:\Users\Steve\Desktop\leakage.hprof"`
- Now your file will converted to leakage.hprof.check this file and
  open it in MAT.

**Edit:** Click *details*,then it will show the class names.In that `Left Click -> Path To GC Roots ->With all references`.Then it shows the class name.

Answer (score 0):

Square open sourced a memory analysis tool: [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary).

The core of the LeakCanary is MAT.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend taking a look at [Leak Canary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary). It's not a memory analyzer per se, but more a leak detector. Just use your app, open and close activities and let the library do it's job. It will even tell you about where the leak occured. Just give the leak analyzer some time to do its work after the leak occured - it usually takes around 2 minutes or more until the source of the leak has been found.

Answer (score -2):

Please update to Android studio version `1.4` or `1.5`.
In this version, android has supported new tool its called `Analyzer Task`
It is very useful to avoid memory leak.