# How to find the origin of a GC_FOR_MALLOC?

Tags: android, garbage-collection

I'm working on an android app which fall into an infinite loop of GC_FOR_MALLOC freed :

```
06-15 11:24:56.685: DEBUG/dalvikvm(118): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 4136 objects / 374744 bytes in 66ms
06-15 11:24:59.176: DEBUG/dalvikvm(521): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 9340 objects / 524152 bytes in 645ms
06-15 11:24:59.846: DEBUG/dalvikvm(521): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 9344 objects / 524328 bytes in 149ms
06-15 11:25:01.535: DEBUG/dalvikvm(521): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 9346 objects / 524448 bytes in 193ms
06-15 11:25:02.175: DEBUG/dalvikvm(521): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 9344 objects / 524344 bytes in 126ms
```

The application read some jpeg image over a socket (dedicated thread) and display it in a imageView. The GC loop is bloking the image display.

Is there a solution to know what line or at least what part of the code is throwing the Garbage collection ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can access the VM and check why it is performing gc all the time, but gc is usually performed when there is a need for it. You should check what is using so much memory. It may be loading your image (is it a big image?) or perhaps it is something else in your app. Check [this post on how to analyse your memory usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080906/memory-analyzer-tool-in-android) and while you are at it check for memory leaks.