# optimize heap size on android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm experiencing troubles issue with an android APP running into outOfMemory.

After dig and searching for memory leak, I discover that - I think - problem is that:

- my initial Heap size is 11 MB (98% used).
- After calling CAMERA intent, the heap size is increased to 34 MB, 99.5% used (rarely crashed cause outOfMemory).
- After rotating the screen or taking another picture my app goes - sometimes to heap size 52 MB (using 70%) and often crash with OutOfMemory.

I read many threads and someone want to increase initial heap size but i read also that should be deprecated soon and it's not a good idea cause increase memory usage even if you don't need it.
Moreover, how can I know how much heap memory my app need? I should still monitor the working and increase time by time with min. step?

My questions is: **what is the best way to handle heap size and avoid this kind of outOfMemory exception?**

I tried with many version of my code and with samples doing only picture with camera, it's always the same. Just for your reference, this is the posted code

[Take picture with android camera (intent) out of memory error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10163071/take-picture-with-android-camera-intent-out-of-memory-error)

Comment: Your original received a valid answer but you didn't accept it. Increasing heap size wont help you if you have a memory leak

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to go through the new article [Displaying Bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) posted on official android developer site..They have just posted this article few days back.

That article surely gonna help you out to solve your problem.

Comment: thanks, great link. I also find this simple version for STEP 1
http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html