# How to Effectively detect without guessing in MAT the memory leaks (android)

Tags: android, memory-management, memory-leaks

When I open MAT with converted hrpof file I get the following

```
Class Name                                                            | Shallow Heap | Retained Heap | Percentage
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
class android.content.res.Resources @ 0x40c51698 Unknown, System Class|           48 |     6,216,112 |     54.20%
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Can some one tell what this means ?

This is asolutely greek to me. how on earth do I know which class in my code is leaking these.
All ideas welcome

Answer (score 0):

Check this link, as this one might take you some deep in theory : [How can I determine if my android app has memory leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064940/how-can-i-determine-if-my-android-app-has-memory-leak)

Use this memory leak info doc : http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html

And give a check to this also : http://novoda.com/blog/blog/memory-debugging-on-android-part-1

Hope all these are helpful for this