# Finding Memory Leak in android app programmatically

Tags: android

I have an android app developed in eclipse and i need to determine whether there is any memory leak in it. I need to achieve it without using any memory leak anaylzer tools, I want to write a piece of code for checking memory leak in the app. Is it possible? Any suggestion would help me.

Comment: try this answer...http://stackoverflow.com/a/11065069/3678308

Answer (score 0):

You're in luck, someone at Square wrote a small library that finds all activity memory leaks  https://github.com/square/leakcanary.  I recommend turning it on only in debug build so you can find all leaks.

Comment: It's a library you add to your project. Completely ide independent. It's actually built on the Eclipse MAT