# Android app slow

Tags: android, memory

I have tried profiling my app, but found that TraceView isn't that user friendly, so I didn't find out why.

I think it may be because I'm allocating too much memory somewhere. So, in the attached image, I am getting these messages once every 2 seconds. Is this a sign of bad memory allocation?

[image: GC_FOR_MALLOC]

Thank you very much,

Richard Hughes

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080906/memory-analyzer-tool-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think that's a problem. GC is just freeing its memory as per its requirement.

To know more about memory allocations, please see following: http://codelog.dexetra.com/getting-around-android-memory-blues
They have explained this wonderfully.

May be this could also be happening because of a memory leak in your app. try to find it out. you can use MAT (plugin) for eclipse, its a bit difficult to understand at the first place, but as you will use it, you will understand, its a very good software to find memory leaks in ours apps.