# Will this Handler still leak Context?

Tags: android, android-context, android-handler

I know that if you initialize a `Handler` directly and use it in an `Activity` it will leak `Context` (courtesy of [Alex Lockwood](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html)), for e.g.

```
public class SampleActivity extends Activity {

  private final Handler mLeakyHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
      /* ... */
    }
  }
}
```

So I used the following approach

```
private static class StaticHandler extends Handler {

    private final WeakReference<SampleActivity> mSampleAct;

    private StaticHandler(SampleActivity act) {
        mSampleAct = new WeakReference<SampleActivity>(
                act);
    }

}
```

Then I initialize it as following

```
 public class SampleActivity extends Activity {
    private Handler myHandler = new StaticHandler(this) {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            processTask(msg.obj);
        }
    };
}
```

I wanted to know if my `Handler` i.e. myHandler will still leak `Context`, how can I be sure it doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `WeakReference` is definitely a smart way to avoid memory leaks. The code looks good to me out of context, but the best way to ensure that it will not leak memory is to use the DDMS memory analyzer. Read more: [Memory Analyzer Tool in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080906/memory-analyzer-tool-in-android)