# Android EdgeEffect appears to allocate a 1 meg bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

We were running [Memory Analyzer Tool](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) in our application to optimize it.  We noticed that it always flags a large 1,127,584 byte Bitmap as a possible memory leak.

During analysis, we realized that it has nothing to do with our app and just creating a simple project with a single layout that contains any scrollable widget will show the same results as shown in the screenshot which flags the Bitmap.

Question is -- anyone know what this image is for and should we be concerned with it?

[image: Possible Leak Suspect report showing a 1.1 meg bitmap]

Comment: Seems like it's related to the overscroll blue glowing you see when you reach the end of a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a late answer but maybe this will help others,I had a similar issue i've seen some big bitmap taking relatively a lot memory in the android studio heap dump, i found out it came from the scrollview so I've added this attribute to the xml to disable the scrollview effects and i dont see this allocation anymore in the heap dump.

android:overScrollMode="never"

p.s
I can see now in the heap dump that the spinner DropDownListVew, when its opened has the same issue

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this **problem is related**, but take a look at my question:

**[Strange Bitmap using 1 Mb of Heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18515647/strange-bitmap-using-1-mb-of-heap)**

> We came to the solution that **the Bitmap is system-related**, and
>   therefore not really of concern to the developer.

Which phone are you using and what are its screen dimensions?

Comment: Ah, thanks Philipp!  Not sure how I overlooked your question before, but it does indeed look to be very similar, if not the same.  I know that the issue I'm seeing goes away as soon as I remove anything with a scrollview (such as a listview, webview, etc).  I'm running on 4.2.2 Emulator with Galaxy Nexus screen dimensions.

Comment: I am also using a ListView. Let me check if the bitmap goes away when removing it.