# Android: Unknown "Bitmap" cause by 'mGlow' causing memory leak?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, bitmap, classloader, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I'm not sure if this is a bug or if it's something I should be worried about.  I'm fairly new to the Eclipse MAT plugin (Memory Analyzer Tool) and when I run a **Leak Suspect Report** I get this:

[image]

Looking further, this is what I see:

[image]

Now, in my app, I load about 8 Bitmaps which I apply to my objects as OpenGL textures.  Once this is done, I call **.recycle()** on all the bitmaps and also set them to **null**.  In addition to this, I have a View class which acts as a splashscreen.  Within this class, I have 1 Bitmap which is loaded, scaled and displayed.  Then again, recycled.

However, and this is the **really bizarre part**.  Just to test and try to track down the problem I have removed **All references to bitmaps** within the whole project.  All declarations, all creations, all calls to recycle etc... completely removed.  I've also then removed the unused imports.

Of course, this renders my application (which is a game) completely useless as it just displays a blank screen, but when I run the **Leak Suspect** report again, this mystery Bitmap is still present!

I've tried to save the raw data and open it up in **The Gimp graphics editor** but it appears to be a somewhat 'blank' picture containing just an alpha channel.  Nothing I can recognise.

Is this a bug of some sort or is it a real problem?  Would appreciate some advise to help me track down the culprit.

This is being run on a Google Nexus 10 tablet running Android 4.4.4

**Edit**

It appears that it's mGlow causing this.  I'm not sure what this is and I haven't explicitly implemented it.  Maybe a bug?  Is there anyway to disable this?

Comment: This might be interesting for you / a **similar issue**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18515647/strange-bitmap-using-1-mb-of-heap

Comment: Thank @PhilippJahoda, just looked at your question.  I'm glad it's not my code - did you ever get an answer to your question of whether it was possible to free the resources used by this?!

Comment: Unfortunately I did not manage to get rid of it, since the Bitmap was associated with the system. I dont know if that is the case with your issue.

Comment: Thanks @PhilippJahoda, can I just ask, I'm assuming this is appearing for all of your apps?