# Android very slow to read file from internal storage

Tags: android, file, save

On my application I need save and load a small xml file. I'd like save and load it on internal storage but I have speed problem for read this file.
This file is very small (about 20/30 lines).
I have try this code:

```
        try {
        FileInputStream file = openFileInput("map.xml");
        int c;
        String xml = "";
        while( (c = file.read()) != -1){
            xml = xml + Character.toString((char)c);
        }

        readXMLdata(xml);

        mapRestore = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

then I have try to save and load the same file to external storage with this code:

```
        String data = "";

    try {
        File myFile = new File(file_xml);
        FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(myFile);
        BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fIn));
        String aDataRow = "";
        String aBuffer = "";
        while ((aDataRow = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
            aBuffer += aDataRow + "\n";
        }
        data = aBuffer;
        myReader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    return data;
```

I have do all test on my Nexus S. If use internal storage I get a lag to read file (some seconds), if I use external storage I don't have it.

Any solution?

Comment: Have you tried the [MAT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080906/memory-analyzer-tool-in-android)?

Comment: Even though I cannot believe that being the true problem, String concatenation is very ineffective as Strings are immutables. I would prefer a StringBuffer of some sort, appending each String in the while loop and calling toString() on the StringBuffer object at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is pretty obvious - just use `BufferedReader`. In your second sample use you use it, but in the first you don't. That's why you have difference in reading performance.

When you have just `FileInputStream` and make calls to `read` method it will actually read data each time from internal storage which is not so fast.
When you use `BufferedReader` or `BufferedInputStream` data will be read into memory buffer first and then when you call `readLine` data is read from this buffer. It dramatically decrease the number of IO operations on internal storage and performs a lot faster.