# Seemingly inconsistent OutOfMemory crashes on different Android devices

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, bitmapfactory

I am making a game which has to load all bitmaps at start because in the in-built game editor the user can put any of the sprites into the level. Also levels use various sprites without any system which would allow to load groups of sprites dynamically for each level.

After a while the are now already 250+ png images in the game with total size of 3.5MB.

The game loads most sprites (about 200) using BitmapFactory.decodeStream without any options set, and also there are about 50 other which are referenced in xml layouts of activities.

When I test on various devices, the game sometimes runs out of memory, but i can't find a pattern and even decide by HOW MUCH i have to, e.g. reduce the size of images or their number.

The phone on which i developed, HTC desire with Android 2.2 24MB VM heap size never runs OOM.

Dell Streak with Android 2.2 and 40MB VM heap size never runs OOM, too.

Motorola Milestone with Android 2.1 and 24MB VM heap size successfully loads all sprites but chokes on the few last images used in ImageView's when starting one of the activities (start menu). If I comment a few of such ImageViews out, it loads ok, but may choke on one of the other activities later. It's also not stable, probably because fragmentation happens differently in different launches.

HTC hero with 2.2 of my buddy (dunno the heap size, is it 16MB?) crashes as well.

What's most confusing is that Motorola has 24MB, the same as HTC desire. Is 2.1 implementing memory management less efficiently? (e.g. leads to more fragmentation?) Or is memory management worse by all Motorola phones? Then why does HTC hero with 2.2 crash? What's bigger in HTC desire than HTC hero?

Looks like OOM happens on older phones, but that's the only thing I've figured out so far.

If OOM only happens on older phones which are, say, 5% of the market, I can just exclude 2.1 or a more specific list from the supported devices by just gathering crash reports and excluding all that crashed from the list of supported. Otherwise I'd now need to scale down all my images by some constant factor (e.g. 1.6), which would mean resizing all the 45 levels which took days and days of designing and testing, repositioning GUI elements etc. Even after that, I'd still not be sure, on which devices the reduction of total size of bitmaps by a factor of e.g. 2 is enough to avoid OOMs.

Any advice on this? 
Should I set any specific options for BitmapFactory? btw, most images have transparent bg pixels which, as far as i understand, doesn't allow getting them in 565 format.

I spent 2 days browsing here and in other places but am still at a loss.

Thank you.

Comment: Just for understanding, how do other developers avoid OOM? I mean, if you know that OOM will happen, you try to make as small and as few bitmaps as possible. On the other hand, for a better game you need as many and as bigger images as possible. What device to take as the one to decide when "it's enough" adding new bitmaps? How can you be sure there isn't still one more other device out there on which an OOM still happens?

Comment: Partially solved the OOM problem by changing the logic of how the engine loads bitmaps. Instead of loading all of them at app launch, now loading only the required sprites when level is started. Now at least the game starts without a crash on Motorola. However, after some browsing around the app, it still crashes with OOM. Placed System.gc() before each call to super.onCreate() in every activity, and this seemed to help as well. Now getting OOM crashes very rarely on Motorola. This of course doesn't make me sure that on other device it would work ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had to deal with a simpler version of your problem - we had 3 2Mpix layers on top of each other, which, unsurprisingly, sometimes caused OOM.

In my case, instead of using 3 ImageViews on top of each other, keeping all 6 MPix in memory at all times, I manually blended the layers, thus keeping at most 4 Mpix in memory at any one time (and only 2 MPix at "rest" - the layers changed in our application).

This is a classic time-space trade-off - sacrifice efficiency (time) to gain memory (space). It was somewhat slow because you had to `recycle()` each Bitmap after you were done with it to ensure the memory was freed.

As for the inconsistent OOMs, it probably has to do with garbage collection. You can assume that the garbage collector is non-deterministic and thus any memory pressure becomes non-deterministic as well (depending on when the GC last kicked in).

The short summary is, you have to be very, very careful with your memory usage and there's no way around it. *****

***** In theory, you could allocate memory outside the Dalvik heap by using the NDK and allocating straight from the OS. It's a huge hack and the bridge between Dalvik and your allocator will be rather ugly.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to find what exactly is using all of your memory. [Check this out.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112671/android-memory-analysing-eclipse-memory-analyzer) Maybe you could be recycling bitmaps, for instance.