# getActivity() returns null when implementing onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, android-activity, orientation, fragment

I want to handle orientation in my android app by implementing `onSaveInstanceState`. I add all the variables that I need to the bundle in the `onSaveInstanceState` method and everything is ok and I can restore them in the `onCreate` method of the same fragment.

The problem is although I can restore all the variables, `getActivity()` has null value.

I tried adding `setRetainInstance(true)` but in this case I couldn't restore the saved variables from bundle.

can anyone help me?
Thanks,

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10854067/1521536) helped me out. It's not straight to your question but I hope it'll help…

Comment: this solution worked for me:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951730/viewpager-and-fragments-whats-the-right-way-to-store-fragments-state the problem was I was creating new instance of the fragments which is not the right way. also I am no longer using setRetainInstance(true)

Comment: Thanks. I think you can answer and accept the answer yourself, to help other people reading your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked for me:[viewpager-and-fragments-whats-the-right-way-to-store-fragments-state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951730/viewpager-and-fragments-whats-the-right-way-to-store-fragments-state) the problem was I was creating new instance of the fragments which is not the right way. also I am no longer using setRetainInstance(true) –