# Android memory leak between activities

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I'm trying to pinpoint this memory leak.

I have two `SurfaceViews`, `A` and `B`. I start `A`, then navigate to `B`, then press the back button to go back to `A`, and then I navigate to `B` again.

I can see my allocated memory rise each time I do this, and eventually I'll get an out of memory error.

Here is how I navigate to `B`, from inside the `SurfaceView` connected to `A`

```
        Context context =  this.getContext();
        Intent i =new Intent(context, StartCareer.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        context.startActivity(i);
```

In both views, I have a lot of Bitmaps drawing. In `B`, I can't find any references to `A`, and the only reference outside the context that I can think of is a reference to a Global class that I have. I also have some analytics stuff going on in the background. It could be a million different things, I'd imagine

I have the DDMS view on Eclipse up, but I'm not sure what I'm looking at, or how to find the exact object that keeps getting repeated.

I'd accept either a crash-course/tutorial on the DDMS Allocation Tracker, or someone to point out what I'm doing wrong.

---

Additional information:

I have some bitmaps being drawn on a `SurfaceView`. Examples of such from `B` are:

```
////At class level
Bitmap rightB,leftB;
////In the constructor
rightB = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.right), 100,75, true);
////In doDraw
canvas.drawBitmap(rightB, rbX, rbY, null);
```

And my onDestroys

```
@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {


    if (mThread.isAlive()){
        mThread.setMenuRunning(false);
    }
}
```

---

So I've run MAT and found one leak, at least. My `Thread` Keeps getting recreated.
Here's what's doing it.

```
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    loading=false;
    if (!mThread.isAlive()){
        mThread = new ViewThread(this);
        mThread.setMenuRunning(true);
        mThread.start();
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    if (mThread.isAlive()){ 
        mThread.setMenuRunning(false);
    }
}
```

Assuming that these methods get called every time the view loses or gains focus, this seems obviously wrong. How can I re-organize this so that it's not?

Comment: Do you have bitmaps on these activities ?

Comment: In the `SurfaceViews` associated with them, yes.

Comment: Paste that code, and your onDestroys

Comment: What does this Global class do? Does it hold any references to any Views, Drawables, Handlers, or anything like that? What about from static variables? There are a number of commonly used objects that keep an entire Activity context in memory.

Comment: @Siddharth done 
@mkuech The Global class holds various ints, strings, oh, and a `Resources`, which is set from  the constructor of `A`

Comment: See, as soon as you said bitmaps you got a bunch of answers.

Comment: Well, I did mention "bitmaps" right under my first block of code

Comment: I updated my question with a known memory leak.

Comment: Now I narrowed down my memory leak, and it is its own question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677913/how-do-i-fix-this-android-memory-leak-involving-threads

Answer (score 4):

Call this method in `onDestroy()` and `onstop()` of your app.

```
private void unbindDrawables(View view) {
     Log.d(TAG,"in unbindDrawables");
        if (view.getBackground() != null) {
        view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
        }
        if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
            for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
            unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
            }
        ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
        view.setBackgroundResource(0);
        Log.d(TAG,"removed views");
        //finish();
        }
 }
```

Comment: I added this into `B`, but it never reaches the second Log statement

Comment: Could you please add some explanation what the code does.

Answer (score 3):

A few hints:

- Recycle bitmaps when done with an activity (onDestroy for example)
- Use the application context rather than the activity itself as context whenever possible

Answer (score 1):

Try to recycle() your bitmaps in onDestroy() of your activities.

Comment: I'll try this, but off the top of my head, I don't know how to access members of the view I created

Comment: You call recycle() on Bitmap objects you created like: Bitmap rightB,leftB; it would be like rightB.recycle();

Comment: Well, I tried recycling all three of the bitmaps I draw in `B`, but it doesn't seem to help. The memory leak still occurs. The problem must be elsewhere

Comment: So, I implemented this, and whenever I exit out of my app, and come back in, it crashes since  the bitmaps that I'm trying to draw are recycled. Maybe because the bitmap is static.

Comment: Static non-trivial members are known to leak context. I would begin the investigation there

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is [explained in detail here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12548203/memory-leak-in-android-when-trying-to-send-a-form-with-image-to-php-server/13448432#13448432). For your specific issue, you need to do this

```
// resize to desired dimensions
    int height = b.getHeight();
    int width = b.getWidth();
    Log.d(TAG, "1th scale operation dimenions - width: " + width + ",
       height: " + height);

    double y = Math.sqrt(IMAGE_MAX_SIZE
            / (((double) width) / height));
    double x = (y / height) * width;

    Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, (int) x, 
       (int) y, true);
    b.recycle();
```

Comment: I'm having memory leaks. I'm not allocating too much memory toward bitmaps

Comment: Regardless of how much memory you are allocating, cleanup is essential. And Bitmaps are known to cause OOM very quickly with relatively small amounts of memory.