# Android HttpClient FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1 using BitmapFactory

Tags: android, bitmap, android-asynctask, httpclient

I'm having a FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1 while trying to upload an image to a webserver From an Android App. I'm using Bitmap and BitmapFactory to encode the image.

```
    @Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    Bitmap bitmapOrg = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(this.path);

    ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    if (bitmapOrg == null)
    {
        return null;
    }


    bitmapOrg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);

    byte[] data = bao.toByteArray();

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost( "http://192.168.20.162/sse_server/up.php" );
    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

    //Set Data and Content-type header for the image
    entity.addPart("file", new ByteArrayBody(data, "image/jpeg", "file"));
    postRequest.setEntity(entity);
    try {

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
    //Read the response
        String jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        Log.v("RequestInformation", "after uploading file " + jsonString);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

And here is the LogCat Errors stack:

```
06-18 09:38:30.270: W/dalvikvm(1394): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
06-18 09:38:30.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1394): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
06-18 09:38:30.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1394): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
06-18 09:38:30.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
06-18 09:38:30.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
06-18 09:38:30.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
06-18 09:38:30.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
06-18 09:38:30.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
06-18 09:38:30.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-18 09:38:30.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-18 09:38:30.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-18 09:38:30.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1394): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
06-18 09:38:30.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
06-18 09:38:30.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:529)
06-18 09:38:30.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:302)
06-18 09:38:30.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:328)
06-18 09:38:30.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at com.example.testapp.HttpTraitement.doInBackground(HttpTraitement.java:75)
06-18 09:38:30.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at com.example.testapp.HttpTraitement.doInBackground(HttpTraitement.java:1)
06-18 09:38:30.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-18 09:38:30.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-18 09:38:30.490: E/AndroidRuntime(1394):     ... 4 more
```

I don't know where comes the error. please Help

Answer (score 1):

Bitmaps are very big memory consumers. Having two loaded into memory could be the big issue. You should consider using BitmapFactory.Options when you decode a new bitmap. 
This can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/13363988/1503155