# OutOfMemoryError at AbstractStringBuilder enlargeBuffer

Tags: android, out-of-memory, stringbuilder

I am reading the youtube response in Stream and converting it to String. using the below code:

URL: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/cnn/uploads?&v=2&max-results=25&alt=json

```
private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }        
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

This code is working in fine in all devices except Android 4.0 devices. I am getting the below logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:94)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:145)
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:216)
        at com.android.mypack.MyApplications.convertStreamToString(MyApplications.java:959)
        at com.android.mypack.MyApplications.access$61(MyApplications.java:951)
        at com.android.mypack.MyApplications$YoutubeTask.doInBackground(MyApplications.java:2303)
        at com.android.mypack.MyApplications$YoutubeTask.doInBackground(MyApplications.java:1)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
        ... 5 more
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:94)
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:145)
        at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:216)
        at com.android.mypack.MyApplications.convertStreamToString(MyApplications.java:959)
        at com.android.mypack.MyApplications.access$61(MyApplications.java:951)
        at com.android.mypack.MyApplications$YoutubeTask.doInBackground(MyApplications.java:2303)
        at com.android.mypack.MyApplications$YoutubeTask.doInBackground(MyApplications.java:1)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Please help me to overcome this error.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How many bytes are coming from this stream?

Comment: @lbalazscs Please see the URL, That is the response i am handling.. I don't know what is the problem with 4.0 devices.

Answer (score 2):

Well, OutOfMemoryErrors are coming obviously when the virtual machine runs out of memory. The important point here is that the exact stack trace might not be informative, because it could happen that another thread uses all of the memory. Or something memory-consuming happened on this thread before this code, and this code was only the "last straw". This URL certainly does not contain too many bytes, I think the problem is in another place.

You could try a memory analyzer:
[Android ==> Memory Analysing ==> Eclipse memory analyzer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112671/android-memory-analysing-eclipse-memory-analyzer)

Comment: huh, I was under the impression the VM would throw this exception after attempting an allocation and failing... That would imply the stack trace is actually useful, and, on top of that, it makes perfect sense for enlarging a buffer to cause an oom exception...

Comment: Of course, the VM will throw this after attempting an allocation and failing. The question is whether this allocation was only the "last straw" after other allocations or the root cause. This stream contains approximately 110 KBytes of data, it shouldn't be to much.

Comment: ahh ok.  yeah, all we can know for sure is this was the last straw.  it is very possible/likely he has a memory leak elsewhere

Comment: how about the String with the length of 276390 ?