# StringBuilder exceeds memory - heap size(16 mib)

Tags: android, sqlite, heap-memory, heap-size

I have an application that requires a big SQLite database within it, now as I add rows to the tables when the heap size of my emulator is 16 MiB, it crashes down saying outofmemory, 32 MiB works fine. and I use a stringbuilder for GET.

So what can I do at this point? Is there a way to limit my application to be used on certain phones  with certain heap sizes? If so specially, how can that be done?

Thanks in advance, here's my error code:

```
09-02 13:21:08.805: E/AndroidRuntime(482): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
09-02 13:21:08.805: E/AndroidRuntime(482): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-02 13:21:08.805: E/AndroidRuntime(482):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
09-02 13:21:08.805: E/AndroidRuntime(482):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
09-02 13:21:08.805: E/AndroidRuntime(482):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
09-02 13:21:08.805: E/AndroidRuntime(482):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
09-02 13:21:08.805: E/AndroidRuntime(482):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
09-02 13:21:08.805: E/AndroidRuntime(482):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
09-02 13:21:08.805: E/AndroidRuntime(482):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
09-02 13:21:08.805: E/AndroidRuntime(482):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
09-02 13:21:08.805: E/AndroidRuntime(482): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
09-02 13:21:08.805: E/AndroidRuntime(482):  at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:97)
09-02 13:21:08.805: E/AndroidRuntime(482):  at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:136)
09-02 13:21:08.805: E/AndroidRuntime(482):  at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:272)
09-02 13:21:08.805: E/AndroidRuntime(482):  at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:452)
09-02 13:21:08.805: E/AndroidRuntime(482):  at com.ex.nok.Src.prodGet(Src.java:157)
09-02 13:21:08.805: E/AndroidRuntime(482):  at com.ex.nok.MainActivity$RestRequ.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:398)
09-02 13:21:08.805: E/AndroidRuntime(482):  at com.ex.nok.MainActivity$RestRequ.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
09-02 13:21:08.805: E/AndroidRuntime(482):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
09-02 13:21:08.805: E/AndroidRuntime(482):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
09-02 13:21:08.805: E/AndroidRuntime(482):  ... 4 more
```

here's where my stringbuilder is, which causes the problem:

```
public static void prodGet (Activity act, String urlStr) {

    int productId;
    String productName;

    UrunSQLiteHelper dbProds = new UrunSQLiteHelper(act);

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    BufferedReader rd = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlStr);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(6000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
        if (conn.getResponseCode() >= 200 && conn.getResponseCode() < 300) {
            rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) { //<<<<<<

                if (line != null || line.length() != 0) {
                JSONTokener prodTokener = new JSONTokener(line);
                JSONArray prodArray = new JSONArray(prodTokener);

                for(int h=0; h<(prodArray.length()); h++)
                {
                    JSONObject json_obj_prd = prodArray.getJSONObject(h);
                    productId = json_obj_prd.getString("PRODID");
                    productName = json_obj_prd.getString("PRODNAME");

                    dbProds.addProduct(new Product(productId, productName));
                }

                dbProds.close();
                }
            }
            rd.close();

            conn.disconnect();

        }
        else {
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("APP", "exception", e);
    }
    finally {
        if (rd != null) {
            try {
                rd.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this related with SQLite? Some `StringBuilder` gets too large.

Comment: well thanks, but how can I get around that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13940218/1066839

Comment: What is the code going to do with that `StringBuilder`?

Comment: @CL. It returns it and then I get the data inside the `StringBuilder` in the `MainActivity` and put it into `SQLite` database

Comment: question is what contains this response ... if JSON then use some stream parsing... if database itself(i doubt but ...) do not store it inside stringbuilder but write to the file at the downloading time, if INSERT statements per line - then execute the line and do not store ... in other words do not use stringbuilder at all - "consume" data on fly

Comment: java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:97)
java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:136)
java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:272)
java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:452)
still it gives this even though I have no StringBuilder

Comment: `com.ex.nok.Src.urunConnGet(Src.java:157)` and `com.ex.nok.MainActivity$RestRequ.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:398)` ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `JsonReader` instead `BufferedReader`

```
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
```

`JsonReader` [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html) provides nice example how to implement it properly.

Alternatively, you can use 3rd party libraries like [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/).

Comment: this is a great solution but I need to be able to use this for API level < 11 devices, is there a solution for that?

Comment: Then use one of the libraries. Both provide Streaming API. Jackson contend to be the most efficient so try it first.

Comment: okay, I will do so if you say so, thanks a lot and sorry for the late reply