# AbstractStringBuilder enlargeBuffer and OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, performance

Not sure what cause this error. Also not sure is that a known error/bug, any explanation or help would be appreciated. Device: Samsung N-900

```
   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
   at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
   Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:94)
   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:145)
   at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:202)
   at org.json.JSONStringer.value(JSONStringer.java:246)
   at org.json.JSONObject.writeTo(JSONObject.java:671)
   at org.json.JSONStringer.value(JSONStringer.java:237)
   at org.json.JSONArray.writeTo(JSONArray.java:572)
   at org.json.JSONStringer.value(JSONStringer.java:233)
   at org.json.JSONObject.writeTo(JSONObject.java:671)
   at org.json.JSONObject.toString(JSONObject.java:640)
   at com.shizup.app.MainActivity$UserProfileAsync.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:683)
   at com.shizup.app.MainActivity$UserProfileAsync.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OutOfMemoryError at AbstractStringBuilder enlargeBuffer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928557/outofmemoryerror-at-abstractstringbuilder-enlargebuffer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have written too much to your String builder, inside your async task. Probably in a loop unintentionally. To the point it overflows the memory and crashes.

Check any While loop conditions are actually met, so they stop.