# Android App crashing on one device only

Tags: android, memory, crash

I am working on a new game that works perfectly on my test devices, 7-inch tablets and smartphones.  But it crashes on my Galaxy Tab2 10-inch tablet with an Out of memory error.  It always crashes when I start to play a second game!  I have spent a full week checking the codes and I cannot figure out what is wrong.

When I play from the menu screen, everything works fine.  When I want to replay a game level from the level screen, the game will crash on the second launch.  The level screen is made of 3 fragments, each with 32 buttons (4kB in size).  I tried to keep only one fragment in memory with viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1); but it does not solve the problem.

Could someone stir me in some direction as to where to look for the potential problem?  Why is the 10-inch tablet the only one to crash?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the device? Try launching the app with only partial resources and see what is the limit where you start to get OOM errors.

Keep [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350465/android-heap-size-on-different-phones-devices-and-os-versions) SO question in mind, some devices will have different amounts of memory available.

Read [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html) Google blog post and see if you can free any resources in your app.

Finally [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112671/android-memory-analysing-eclipse-memory-analyzer) the memory of your app as you debug and see how memory efficient you can make your app. If all of the above fails you might just have to say that your app is incompatible with that particular device.

Comment: Thanks for the tips KDEx. I will try that. I am not an expert in using Debug in Eclipse but I will certainly dive more into it in the next few days.  This OOM error really bugs me!

Comment: I tried with only one fragment page open (instead of three) and it does not crash.  Each fragment only has 32 buttons and they are 4kB each.  There is no background bitmap either.  So I find rather strange that a good tablet like the Tab2 would crash on this!!!

Comment: I just discovered that the heap size on the Tab2 10.1 is only 50MB.  It is 67MB on my Lenovo 7-inch and on the S3! I now need to be more efficient with my memory usage from the 3 fragments. But I am puzzled by the smaller heap on the Tab2!

Comment: I'm not surprised, I've experienced the same issue with samsung devices. Check out the links and see if you can free up some memory. The profiler is really helpful in conjunction with the blog post from google. You might have to adapt according to that device by detecting it and loading different resources, or decide if its worth it to even support it.

Comment: I reduced the background image of the 3 fragment pages and it seems to work now on the Tab2 10.1.  I thought a device would adjust the heap size dynamically when needed by an App?